# How to have several flows in a menu of a template?

Tags: jsf, faces-flow

All the pages of an application use a template with a menu containing links toward several different flows. If a choice of the menu enters a flow with a GET request (`<h:link>` for instance), an error is produced when the user enters another flow ("no navigation case" for the flow which uses `<h:link outcome="flow">`).

If I enter a flow with a POST request (with `<h:commandLink>` for instance), the address displayed in the navigator is not good like with any POST request (the address of the previous page is displayed). If I add "?faces-redirect=true" to the address of the flow in the menu (`<h:commandLink action="flow?faces-redirect=true">`, I get an error "no navigation case".

How can I do?

Comment: Did you managed to solved it ?